# Add margin to the <html> element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking to add some top margin to the entire  but I think I'm not referring to the element properly.

This is what I have:

```
getElementsByTagName("html").style.marginTop = top_height;
```

I'm guessing there must be another way to refer to the `<html>` tag since it's kind of a unique tag, but I haven't found how to after a lot of searching. I'm probably not running the right searches. Hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your feedback! In the end you were right, adding the margin to the body worked better, this is the code that ended up working for me: document.body.style.marginTop = top_height;

Answer (score 3):

You should apply the margin to the `body` instead as it is the root of the visible elements.

Also, `getElementsByTagName` is off of `document` and returns an list of elements.  `document.querySelector('body')` will return the first one or you could just use `document.body` as Jaromanda recommended.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm guessing there must be another way to refer to the `<html>` tag since it's kind of a unique tag

There is. In fact, there is a property of `document` for it. It is [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement).

This property brings with it improved performance, as it does not need to run any document queries, and can be used to access the root element with other document types, such as SVG.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding margin to the body instead of the !DOCTYPE html attribute.

```
getElementsByTagName("body").style.marginTop = top_height;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `document.` before the `getElementsByTagName` and then since this particular function returns an array of matched tags you can do the following (try it in your browser Console and watch stackoverflow shift down 6 pixels):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.marginTop = "6px";
```

Like [@Alexander O'Mara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155639/alexander-omara) mentioned the `document.documentElement` is a much better way to access the html element so then your code would be like this:

```
document.documentElement.style.marginTop = "6px";
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to. Thanks! :) (I would love to vote you up but I don’t have enough reputation yet...)